# Reference an XLS Picklist from MSAccess VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access app that exports a table to XLS then applies formatting.

I am trying to create a picklist for a range of cells on worksheet 1 ("Expenses"), from a list of values from worksheet 2 ("Expense Types") in the same workbook.

I used "record Macro" from XLS to get started. The picklist does work from XLS, but fails when trying to implement from MSAccess VBA.

Here is the snippet that is failing (err 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error)

```
' Validation

With wks1.Range("G4:G10").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="= wbk.Sheets('Expense Types')!$B$3:$B$10"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

wks1.Range("A4").Select
```

Guessing pretty straightforward once I know the required format/syntax to reference the source and destination info for the picklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wbk.Sheets('Expense Types')` is VBA (sort of) and doesn't belong in the `Formula1` argument.

Try:

```
Formula1:="='Expense Types'!$B$3:$B$10"
```

**EDIT**
If you haven't already declared those constants and you're using late binding then you need to add:

```
Const xlValidateList = 3
Const xlValidAlertStop = 1
Const xlBetween = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but no luck with the alternate construction.  I also tried a few variants moving around the single quotes with no success.

Comment: Are you using late binding, or have you added a reference to Excel in your access VB project?

Comment: Hi Tim,  Sorry for delay.  Yes, Late Binding in-use.  XLS automation is fully working in all other aspects but this, so far.

Comment: If late binding, all *xl* constants need to be explicitly declared. Please show fuller code block so we can see your process

Comment: @Tim - Declaring those Constants was exactly my issue.  Great point for future reference. - Thanks!